# Adding 20px height to variable height post container

Tags: javascript, height

I am using javascript similar to what Pinterest uses that creates variable height divs with the same amount of spacing. The issue I am having is that the bottom margin on the last div in mobile view is 20px shorter than it should be. I discovered that if I inspect the element and add 20px to the height of the container which holds all the posts it looks like it should. I'm just not sure how I can do this in the code itself since it is a calculated height that is applied via javascript.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="post-container" class="grid_4_desktop grid_4_tablet grid_1_mobile">
        <?php 
            if($year !==''){
        ?>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="news_articles" start_on="<?php echo $year-1;?>-12-31 00:01" stop_before="<?php echo $year;?>-12-31 00:01" orderby="date"  sort"desc" }
        <?php 
            }else{
        ?>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="news_articles" orderby="date" sort"desc" limit="15"}
        <?php
            }
        ?>

        <div class="post">
             <a href="{path=news/article/{url_title}}?year={entry_date format='%Y'}">
                 {if article_thumb!=''}
                    <img width="216" height="143" title="Meeting" src="{article_thumb}" />
                 {/if}
            </a>
            <div class="inner small">
                <p class="date">{entry_date format="%D %F %d, %Y"}</p>
                <h3 class="title">
                    <a href="{path=news/article/{url_title}}?year={entry_date format='%Y'}">{article_title}</a>
                </h3>
                <p>{exp:ce_str:ing truncate='120|...<br /><a href="{path=news/article/{url_title}}?year={entry_date format='%Y'}">Read More</a>'}{article_content}{/exp:ce_str:ing}</p>


                <div class="social clearfix">
                    <a href="javascript:createFacebookLink('{current_url}','<?php shuffle($fbShareTxt); echo $fbShareTxt[0];?>', '{article_title}', '{site_url}_img/_layout/logo_orange_200x200.png');" class="icon facebook"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:createTwitterLink('{current_url}','<?php shuffle($fbShareTxt); echo $fbShareTxt[0];?>');"class="icon twitter"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div><!-- end post-container -->
```

And the script which sets the height:

```
function setNewsGrid(columns,columnWidth,offset){
      $('#post-container').show();
            var item, top, left, i=0, plength=$('#post-container .post').length, cHeight=0;
            for(; i<plength; i++ ) {
              item = $('#post-container .post:eq('+i+')');
              var t = 0;
              if(i-columns > -1){
                t =  $('#post-container .post:eq('+(i-columns)+')').outerHeight() +  $('#post-container .post:eq('+(i-columns)+')').position().top +offset;
              }
              // Postion the item.
              item.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: t,
                left: (((i%columns)*columnWidth) + ((i%columns)*offset))+'px'
              });
              if(t+item.outerHeight() > cHeight)cHeight=t+item.outerHeight();
            }
          $('#post-container').css('height',cHeight);
      }
```

Basically I just want to add 20px to the height that is generated so that the bottom margin doesn't cut off the final div.

Comment: When asking about JavaScript, please post HTML, not server-side code. In any case, I'd guess a CSS fix is a better approach. Overflow on the wrapper element, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried everything I can think of on the wrapper with no luck. The only way I can get it to display properly is to remove the 20px margin or to manually add 20px to the height of the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I just changed this line:

```
if(t+item.outerHeight() > cHeight)cHeight=t+item.outerHeight();
```

To this:

```
if(t+item.outerHeight() > cHeight)cHeight=t+20+item.outerHeight();
```

And now it is working exactly like it should.